# Provide a selection area on UIImagePicker Controller to capture the selected area alone?

Tags: ios, user-interface, uiimageview, uiimagepickercontroller, crop

After Googled a whole day I was unable to get any model for my need. Actually my need is

1.Provide a Selection area box on `UIImagePicker` like the image below:

[image]

2.User can `resize` the selection area so that both width and height can be modified.

3.Once the area selected, if user presses the capture button, the selected portion alone should be captured.

Is it possible to implement all above features?Please suggest some good tutorials.

And also the requirement for `UIImageView`.If I take the image from photo library, I am displaying the selected image.Here I want to provide the User can select the portion of the image and crop it before it is used.

Please suggest some solution.

Thank you.

Comment: Whole day? Wow... https://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView

Comment: @JackyBoy : Just now I checked the code you referred.But its just resizing the imageView.I want to select the portion of the image and crop the selected portion alone.

Comment: Well, we can't have everything. That is just a starter.

Comment: @JackyBoy : Is it possible to implement the requirement I want? any idea? Bcz I am struggling a lot in this.

Comment: Everything is possible, the sky is the limit. Yes of course it can be implemented.

Comment: @JackyBoy : Can you help me in this? How can I achieve this?.Please your idea as an answer.

Answer (score 2):

I am not going to give you the full answer for this, just some starting points:

- Use the [library](http://github.com/spoletto/SPUserResizableView) I pointed you, on the comments.
- Implement the delegate, because it returns what you want:

> Then implement the following delegate methods.
>
> - (void)userResizableViewDidBeginEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView;
> - (void)userResizableViewDidEndEditing:(SPUserResizableView *)userResizableView